# Having issue setting up Custom url for blogger

Tags: blogger

Am trying to setup a custom url for my blog on blogger.com. I have thoroughly followed the steps highlighted on http://helplogger.blogspot.com.ng/2014/07/how-to-set-up-custom-domain-in-blogger.html. But when am trying to change my DNS setting to that provided by blogger i keep having the error message below.

> CNAME|www|ghs.google.com - Record does not exist.
>
> CNAME|xj6b46j7wnuq|gv-uun7e2hpmvy34q.dv.googlehosted.com - Record does not exist.

I contacted my Hosting company and they are of no help. Please does anyone know what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix the issue. I requested from my Hosting Company the main access to my Domain control of which they gave me. Getting to the Domain control Center i set of the CName details as specified by Google and it was accepted without any error.

So the issue was that the CName details CANNOT be changed from the Administrative Center provided on my Hosting Company site.

Hope thats clear enough!